# Connection to google cloud sql fails on dev

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to the Dev SQL server on Google's cloud platform.
I used to have no problem at all connecting a few weeks ago but I wanted to upgrade some stuff and suddenly a connection cannot be established..

I've tried connecting via MySQL Workbench first and it keeps getting a connection error 10060. When I test the parameters it goes fine but the connection never succeeds.
So I also tried using code in Java using a code similar to Google's example and this arbitrarily works but mostly doesn't and throws connection link fail exception. 
So I know the code and setup is fine since it sometimes succeeds. so the question is: why? When is it fine and when does it fail and why? Also why does it never work via the workbench although it did work in the past?

Is this familiar to anyone?

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same problem.
I read that it might be the ISP blocking outbound port 3306.

is your IPS is Bezeq International-Ltd by any chance?

when I use my cell phone network it works fine.

Comment: Maybe they got plenty of other complaints since it seems to work fine now. Simply out of the blue it started working :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Google are currently having issues with Cloud SQL. See Twitter for example

Comment: Can you share the #tag for the cloud sql? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I searched it on twitter and found this [cloud status](https://status.cloud.google.com/).
Although the status is back and the issue is fixed, I still can't connect to my instance...
Thanks for your help though